# What is the significance of "Publisher domain" in AAD app registration

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have registered the app in 2017 which accepts the url with query string parameter, but the other app i registered last week does not accept the query string parameter in the reply_url (it looks exact match with registered url). Both the app the registered url is not having any wildcard symbol. One difference i see is Publisher domain and created date.

What is the publisher domain and why it is null in one app another app has tenant name as value, eventhouh it is a read only property. I have attached the screenshot of manifest file here. can anyone comment the difference in behavior related to created date/publisher domain or something else changed by AAD itself?

[image]

Comment: Done, Thanks for your response MD Farid Uddin Kiron!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the publisher domain is displayed to users on the application’s consent prompt to let users know where their information is being sent. When you register a new app, the publisher domain of your app may be set to a default value.

The publisher domain which in the previously registered app is null by default while the default value of publisher domain which in the currently registered app(the application is registered in the tenant) is *.onmicrosoft.com.

You can view and update the publisher domain in the App registration section.

[image]

For more details, this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-configure-publisher-domain) is for your reference.